# blender 2.77a and 2.78b crashes whenever I click an object in 3Dmodeling window

Tags: modeling

blender 2.77a and 2.78b crashes whenever I click an object in 3Dmodeling window. However 2.76b works flawlessly in all respects. I am ble to select camera and lamp in 3D window and any object I want in properties panel. Am using linux 17.3 on toshiba laptop dual core intel

Comment: There were some OpenGL changes inbetween versions I think, your computer's graphics card may no longer be supproted.

Comment: thanx for answer. Blender now works fine after upgrading Linux to 18.1 must have been a compatibility issue with outdated 17.3. Your sugg thatOpen Gl is a problem is valid however (AwesomeBump still doesn't work) but not it seems for blender at this time